# How to unit test an rxjs observable with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, rxjs

Given the following function that returns an observable :

```
retrieveAll = (): Observable<Well[]> =>
  from(this.wellRepository.retrieveAssets()).pipe(
    map((assets: Asset[]) => this.mapper.mapping(assets)),
    catchError(() => {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    })
  );
```

I try to test it like this :

```
describe("Api Well Repository", () => {
  it("should retrieve wells", (done) => {
    const apiWellRepository = new ApiWellRepository(
      new InMemoryWellRepository()
    );

    const observable$: Observable<Well[]> = apiWellRepository.retrieveAll();
    observable$.subscribe((wells: Well[]) =>
      expect(wells).toStrictEqual([
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "Angola_0",
        },
      ])
    );
  });
});
```

My InMemoryWellRepository returns an async array :

```
export class InMemoryWellRepository {
  private readonly assets: Asset[] = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Angola",
    },
  ];

  retrieveAssets = async (): Promise<Asset[]> => this.assets;
}
```

This test fails because of timeout.

If I voluntary expect something wrong, I also get a timeout but it says that deep equality is not respected. So it seems that my test is working but somehow, it doesn't hand over and timeout.

Comment: I believe you need to call `done` in your subscription handler.

Comment: I still have the timeout. I added `done()` after the `expect`

Comment: Is there anything you need to do to get your `InMemoryWellRepository` to emit a response? I work with Angular HTTP client and there is an explicit `flush` method that must be called to cause the observable to emit. Also, I work with Jasmine not Jest, but it looks pretty similar. In Jasmine, I would not pass `done` to this type of test.

Comment: `InMemoryWellRepository` doesn't emit anything. It returns an async array. In my use case, WellRepository returns a promise. I updated the code to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to call `done` inside the `observable.subscribe()` method after assertions. I will use [jestjs](https://jestjs.io/) as a test runner to illustrate, other test runners(mocha, jasmine) are the same. See [asynchronous#callbacks](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks)

> jest will wait until the `done` callback is called before finishing the test

> If `done()` is never called, the test will fail (with timeout error), which is what you want to happen.

`InMemoryWellRepository.ts`:

```
export type Asset = any;

export class InMemoryWellRepository {
  private readonly assets: Asset[] = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Angola',
    },
  ];

  retrieveAssets = async (): Promise<Asset[]> => this.assets;
}
```

`ApiWellRepository.ts`:

```
import { catchError, from, map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Asset, InMemoryWellRepository } from './InMemoryWellRepository';

export type Well = any;

export class ApiWellRepository {
  mapper = {
    mapping: (arr) => arr.map((v, i) => ({ ...v, name: `${v.name}_${i}` })),
  };
  constructor(private wellRepository: InMemoryWellRepository) {}

  retrieveAll = (): Observable<Well[]> =>
    from(this.wellRepository.retrieveAssets()).pipe(
      map((assets: Asset[]) => this.mapper.mapping(assets)),
      catchError(() => {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong');
      }),
    );
}
```

`ApiWellRepository.test.ts`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiWellRepository, Well } from './ApiWellRepository';
import { InMemoryWellRepository } from './InMemoryWellRepository';

describe('Api Well Repository', () => {
  it('should retrieve wells', (done) => {
    const apiWellRepository = new ApiWellRepository(new InMemoryWellRepository());

    const observable$: Observable<Well[]> = apiWellRepository.retrieveAll();
    observable$.subscribe((wells: Well[]) => {
      expect(wells).toStrictEqual([
        {
          id: '1',
          name: 'Angola_0',
        },
      ]);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS   v7  packages/v7/stackoverflow/ApiWellRepository.test.ts
  Api Well Repository
    ✓ should retrieve wells (3 ms)

---------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                  |      95 |      100 |   88.88 |   92.85 |                   
 ApiWellRepository.ts      |    92.3 |      100 |   85.71 |      90 | 16                
 InMemoryWellRepository.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.149 s
```

package versions:

```json
"rxjs": "^7.8.1",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
```